# Calculating Total Sales from Multiple MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to determine the total sales for an employee using MySQL. The DB has 4 tables in it that will help determine the total sales.  I was able to create a Query that selects all the necessary tables to calculate the Sales Total.

Query:

```
SELECT employees.eno, employees.ename, orders.ono, orders.eno, 
    parts.pno, parts.price,odetails.ono, odetails.pno, odetails.qty
FROM test.employees, test.parts, test.orders, test.odetails
WHERE employees.eno = orders.eno AND parts.pno = odetails.pno
```

This comes up with a Table that displays the Employee's name, Item, price it's sold at.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  And any help would be much appreciated!  I'm not sure if a stored procedure would help, then I could call it in a Java program to print out the results.  Just really confused here.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: You can use `SUM` and multiply by your quantity field to get the total. Trouble with `sum` is that it grouped your results as well, in which case you can `join` the query to itself to return the records as well if you want all that data as well. It I were you, I would select all the records, and run a seperate query that **only** selects the total sales (if you don't want your results to be grouped)

Comment: I want to basically find which employee has the highest total sales according to price. Price* qty.  Just not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT employees.eno, employees.ename, SUM(parts.price * odetails.qty) as TotalSales
FROM test.employees
INNER JOIN test.orders
ON empoyee.eno = orders.eno
INNER JOIN test.odetails
ON orders.ono = odetails.ono
INNER JOIN test.parts
ON odetails.pno = parts.pno
GROUP BY employees.eno, employees.ename
```

Comment: No problem @Bob. I'm just hoping that my wife does not see your comment here...lol. Happy coding and GOD bless!

Answer (score 0):

The following *should* work.

```
SELECT employees.ename, COUNT(employees.ename), (COUNT(employees.ename) * parts.price) FROM test.employees INNER JOIN (orders, parts) ON (employees.eno = orders.eno AND parts.pno = odetails.pno)
```

Comment: Will return total **number** of sales (number of records), which you could then add totals with a server side code to get the total amount, or you'll need to select a `SUM` also

Comment: Alright, so I modified your sql script a little, and it did give me the correct amount of sales. But, I have 4 employees in the DB, and I want to figure out the amount of sales for each of them, then calculate the profit by doing the sales*price of the item.                                    _SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test.employees INNER JOIN (orders, parts, odetails) ON (employees.eno = orders.eno AND parts.pno = odetails.pno)_

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JOIN`s to join all your tables together into the appropriate results. Here's an example from what I can tell from your query/database structure that will return each order, joining the order details, part information and employee info:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM test.orders O
LEFT JOIN test.odetails OD ON OD.pno = O.ono
LEFT JOIN test.employees E ON E.eno = O.eno
LEFT JOIN test.parts P ON P.pno = OD.pno
```

From here, if you want to get a total **per employee**, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
E.eno,
SUM(OD.qty * P.price) AS employee_total
...
GROUP BY E.eno
```

...which should return the employee number and total of all prices associated which each order, multiplied by the quantity for each order, and grouped by the employee number.

You could then add:

```
ORDER BY employee_total ASC -- or DESC...
```

To order from lowest to highest or vice versa.